# How to build a HTML5 game dev framework

Tags: javascript, html, frameworks

I have an interesting for me question. Now I was getting started to using HTML5 game dev frameworks like Contruct2, Quintus, Phaser and etc. I'm wondering now, is it hard to build your own HTML5+JS framework? Because I'm kind of interested in it, exactly in building. 
What for example I need to do? Any articles/books explaining this kind if stuff. 
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you begin with understanding how the existing frameworks have done it? You could decide to adopt them, or learn and build your own. But ask yourself this, why would you want to re-invent the wheel? It might be better to focus on the game you want to build, instead of the tools to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many people using game frameworks but relatively few who build them. Some colleges offer game design as subject but they also use existing frameworks - it's very time consuming to build a new engine from the ground up.

Google for "book game engine javascript" to get some links but my suggestion would be to take an existing engine and play with it. Build a couple of games to learn what games need and then start to fix the problems in the engine.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/JavaScript-Short-Subjects-Building-Engine-ebook/dp/B00AXE5ITG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1382346425&sr=8-1&keywords=JavaScript+Short+Subjects%3A+Building+a+2D+Game+Engine) I will take a look at it a bit later but still I will follow, your advice, thank you.